# messageReactionAdd can't add roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a private discord bot for a server. I've seen a few bots like SweeperBot and some others use a reaction collector to assign roles. Most of them aren't discord.js, so I coded my own.

I have the `messageReactionAdd` event setup, and the whole block of code works, I have tested every line. One line, in particular, errors every time.

```
exports.run = (bot, reaction, user) => {
  const rmsg = reaction.message;
  if (rmsg.channel === rmsg.guild.channels.find('name', 'rules') && rmsg.id === '457681660708651010' && reaction.emoji.name === '') {
    const member = rmsg.guild.fetchMember(user)
    const MemberRole = rmsg.guild.roles.find('name', 'Mythical Member');
    member.addRole(MemberRole).catch(console.error);
  }
};
```

The last line, `member.addRole(MemberRole).catch(console.error);`, is the errored line, sending `TypeError: member.addRole is not a function` every time a reaction is added.

Everything else works, as I did test it before this.

I have tried testing different approaches to this `member` variable, as I know the `user` is not a `GuildMember` object.

I am trying to convert it into one using `const member = rmsg.guild.fetchMember(user)` and it does work, returning the `GuildMember` object, but when put into the `addRole` line, it errors. I have used `addRole` in many other commands, in this same way, but maybe events simply cannot use that? Am I simply missing something obvious? I've checked the docs many times and asked in so many discord servers, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

[`guild.fetchMember()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchMember) doesn't return a GuildMember. Instead it returns a Promise. You need to wait until you have the response of that Promise (It will be a GuildMember) and then give the role.
A couple ways you could do this:
Using `.then()`:

```
const MemberRole = rmsg.guild.roles.find('name', 'Mythical Member');
rmsg.guild.fetchMember(user).then(member => {
    member.addRole(MemberRole).catch(console.error);
})
```

Or switching the whole method to async:

```
exports.run = async (bot, reaction, user) => {
```

And then wait until you got a response from `fetchMember`:

```
const member = await rmsg.guild.fetchMember(user);
```