# Getting an error in discord.js when I try to add roles through reactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to add roles from reactions. I am getting this error. `Cannot read property 'add' of undefined.` Here is my code below.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    const listen = message.content; 
    if(message.author.bot) {
        if(message.embeds) {
            const embedMsg = message.embeds.find(msg => msg.title === 'Choose your favorite team!');
            if(embedMsg) {
                message.react('797575748307255316')
                .catch(err => console.error)
            }

        }
        return; 
    }

    if(listen.toLowerCase() === '!claim roles1') {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Choose your favorite team!")
            .setColor("BLUE")
            .setDescription("<:76ers:797575748307255316> - Philadeplhia 76ers\n"); +
          
            
        message.channel.send(embed)

        return; 
    }
})

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(user.bot) return; 
    var roleName = reaction.emoji.name; 
    var role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase());
    var member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);
    reaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user).then(m => m.roles.add(role).then(member => {
        console.log('Added ' + member.user.username + ' to the ' + role.name + ' role.');
    })) 
    if(member.guild.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
        reaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user).then(m => m.roles.remove(role).then(member => {
            console.log('Removed ' + member.user.username + ' from the ' + role.name + ' role.');
        })) 
    }

})
```

I use Discord.MessageEmbed in order to display it nicely and it is supposed to make the user get a role by them reacting to the reaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using `.some()` which only returns `true` or `false`. Use `.find()` instead in both cases (`role` and `member`).

Edit:
Try this:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(user.bot) return; 
    var roleName = reaction.emoji.name; 
    var role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase());
    reaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user).then(m => m.roles.add(role).then(member => {
        console.log('Added ' + member.user.username + ' to a role.');
    }))
})
```

Comment: I am getting another error. Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

Comment: Ok can you console log `role` and `member` and give me the output of both?

Comment: For role it says undefined and for member it gives me a bunch of information about the author I guess. Ex: my user id, username, etc.

Comment: Hm and your reaction emoji has the same name as the role?

Comment: I resolved the previous issue by changing the reaction emoji to the same name. However, now it doesn't add the role. I updated my code.

Comment: @CodingMaster edited my answer try to add the role like this.

Comment: I modified my code as you said, however it still isn't adding the role.

Comment: okay thats weird what if you directly try to add the role to `user`? If this works you can delete `member`. Sorry btw I've never worked with `messageReactionAdd`.

Comment: It didn't work. This is probably because it would not work in the user object because you cannot add role to the user, but rather the member.

Comment: Yes therefor I created a GuildMember Object in my answer and I am wondering why this doesn't work

Comment: @CodingMaster edited my answer again, I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892905/messagereactionadd-cant-add-roles)

Comment: There is a discord api error after I tried your code, meaning that one of the settings or permissions are off or on. Do you know which one exactly?

Comment: Make sure the bot has a higher role then `role` and that it has permissions to give roles.

Comment: Yes, the bot has control over everything

Comment: Ok [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions-extended.html#limitations-and-oddities) you can get more information

Comment: Yes, thank you I fixed the API error. How do you remove the role when the user unreacts to the reaction. I updated my code but it isn't working as intended.

Comment: That is done in an event called `messageReactionRemove`. [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionRemove) you can see which parameters it takes in.

Comment: I guess its the same code, but instead of adding the role, you have to remove the role, inside the `messageReactionRemove` event.